# Using ftp.exe to create some kind of log

Tags: cmd, ftp, command-prompt

I have a situation that a create a ftp script to run with FTP.exe (Windows). But I'm looking for somehow to extract a log, in other words, to know if the script had run successful or not. In a automated way*.

Follows the script:

```
open xxx 'replace ftp.server with the server address
usr 'login id here
pwd" 'login password here
quote pasv 'passive mode
mget *.xlsx 'download files
disconnect 'disconnect the session
bye
exit
```

thanks for the help.